# System.exe psreturnprocessnonpagedpoolquota thread high CPU (100% of a core)?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 (1903, installed all updates, excluding the infamous one that breaks search). When returning from sleep, sometimes the CPU usage keeps being about 25%. Since I have 4 cores, that is probably 100% for 1 core. In the Task Manager, "System" is consuming 25%. In Process Explorer, I could see that the `psreturnprocessnonpagedpoolquota` thread is consuming 25%. What is that?

I tried killing all applications and all killable processes ("system" is not killable), yet the CPU usage remained 25%. The only way was logging out and logging in again. But this is not a solution as I have to close all the applications.

What is the solution?

Comment: This is happening to me also - I just wanted to support the position that you aren't crazy, and this isn't a one-off for your machine. @ypsilon09's solution to disable a USB Composite Device worked for me as well (how the heck they found that solution is pretty mysterious!).

Comment: Also FWIW, I'm on a Lenovo Thinpad T480, in case this might be a faulty driver update related to manufacturer..

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced symptoms similar to you.I found a solution in my environment and will share it.

I investigated using Windows Performance Analyzer. As a result, I found that Wdf01000.sys! FxUsbPipeContinuousReader is using a lot of CPU.

When I disabled one USB Composite Device in Device Manager, the CPU usage rate dropped.Now CPU usage of System.exe is 0.1%.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This has not happened for several days to me. If it happens again, I will try this.

Comment: This is happening to me as well, and disabling a USB Composite Device also fixes the issue. Now my questions are what was that Composite Device doing? And, what function was that Composite Device playing in my system? (What functions are disabled now that this Device is disabled?) cc @ypsilon09